# Can we share a survey in SharePoint without requesting for any authentication

Tags: office-365

Can we open a survey in SharePoint (office 365) for all users?

For example, anyone can visit the survey link and submit their response.

I am not able to find any links for this requirement, all links describe only about making survey feedback anonymously.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just set survey permission and send an email invitation to them? 
Go to Site Content > click on ... on survey list you want to share > settings > Survey permission

or here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-permissions-on-a-survey-a1ea7488-b16b-464b-a5f5-a89428df6b8d

Comment: but that would require a login right 
I want it to be open like a survey monkey survey

Comment: @vignesh sorry man, I thought you were asking sharing survey with all users and not just anonymous

Answer (score 1):

Hope this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Surveys-in-Excel-hosted-online-5fafd054-19f8-474c-97ec-b606fcda0ff9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) helps. You can create survey in excel and share the link to anybody for them to complete the survey anonymously.

Comment: thanks Phani, I had a look at the forms, but I wanted to add some css which is why I thought  I will use sharepoint survey so that I can customize the look and feel